# C# filter based on request api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to filter the posts that are displayed in my application. Everything goes like expected, but I have a small issue. A user can choose the education(s) and profession(s) he follows. How can I filter based on the arrays I get? I tried something like this, but it feels ugly. If I set more arrays in my Filter class like Language[].. It wil get more messy. Can I do something easier?

```
public class Filter
{
    public string[] Education { get; set; }

    public string[] Profession { get; set; }
    public int PageIndex { get; set; }

}
```

Example request:
[image: An example]

```
public PaginatedResults<Post> FilterPosts(Filter filter)
{

// Both Education and Profession arrays are empty, we just return all the posts
    if(filter.Profession.Any(prof => prof == null) && filter.Education.Any(study => study == null)) {
        var posts1 = _dbContext.Posts.AsEnumerable();
        return _searchService.Pagination<Post>(posts1, filter.PageIndex);
    }
    else 
    {
        // Can this be simplified? Sometimes the Education array is empty and sometimes Profession array. User can choose
        IEnumerable<Post> posts = null;
        if(filter.Profession.Any(prof => prof == null)) 
        {
            posts = _dbContext.Posts.Where(post => filter.Education.Contains(post.Education)).AsEnumerable();
        }
        else if(filter.Education.Any(study => study == null)) 
        {
            posts = _dbContext.Posts.Where(post => filter.Profession.Contains(post.Profession)).AsEnumerable();
        }
        else 
        {
            posts = _dbContext.Posts.Where(post => filter.Profession.Contains(post.Profession) && filter.Education.Contains(post.Education)).AsEnumerable();
        }
        return _searchService.Pagination<Post>(posts, filter.PageIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably quite a few ways you could approach this problem. Assuming you want to keep your approach (which I think is perfectly valid), you could try the following steps:

#### Leverage `IQueryable`

Assuming you use entity framework, I believe `_dbContext.Posts` implements [`IQueryable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable?view=netcore-3.1) already. Since LINQ does not get executed immediately, we can build filtering conditions sequentially before enumerating the collection:

```
posts = _dbContext.Posts.Where(post => filter.Education.Contains(post.Education) && filter.Education.Contains(post.Profession)).AsEnumerable();

// since you are implementing `AND` semantics for your filters, is easy to break down into series of `.Where()` calls
posts = _dbContext.Posts.Where(post => filter.Education.Contains(post.Education))
                        .Where(post => filter.Education.Contains(post.Profession))
                        .AsEnumerable(); // this should filter Posts by Education AND Profession as well as represent the result as IEnumerable. Should be functionally identical to the first statement
```

#### Invert boolean conditions and check if filters *have* values

This will allow you to add a `.Where` filter only when it's needed:

```
if (filter.Profession.Any()) // if Profession has elements
{
    posts = posts.Where(post => filter.Profession.Contains(post.Profession)); // apply respective filter to posts, you may want to ensure you only compare against meaningful search terms by appplying `.Where(i => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i))` to it
}
if (filter.Education.Any()) // if Education has elements
{
    posts = posts.Where(post => filter.Education.Contains(post.Education)).AsEnumerable(); // apply respective filter to posts          
}
```

#### Then, to put it all together

```
public PaginatedResults<Post> FilterPosts(Filter filter)
{
    IQueryable<Post> posts = _dbContext.Posts;
    if (filter.Profession.Any()) posts = posts.Where(post => filter.Profession.Contains(post.Profession));

    if (filter.Education.Any()) posts = posts.Where(post => filter.Education.Contains(post.Education));

    return _searchService.Pagination<Post>(posts.AsEnumerable(), filter.PageIndex); 
}
```

Comment: This seems right in principle and advice but I'm suspicious of the use of `IEnumerable<Post> posts = _dbContext.Posts;`, this can have unforeseen implications.

Comment: @AluanHaddad oh, it's a copy-paste artifact. Should probably be `IQueryable` or `var`. I'll update it when I get a chance

Comment: I really like the approach, but there is one problem which I didn't explain properly. When I call my api like: ```api/posts/filter?profession=ICT&education=&pageIndex=1``` The education or profession can be empty. Thats why I posted the picture above. For example education is empty: ```filter.Education[0]``` becomes null and ```filter.Education.Any()``` becomes true. ```.Where(post => filter.Education.Contains(post.Education))``` becomes 0 posts because I dont have any Education with null. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: ``` if(filter.Profession.Any(prof => prof != null)) 
 {
                    posts = posts.Where(post => filter.Profession.Contains(post.Profession));
                }``` Oh I did this and it worked. Thank you for the provided help. I now understand how to build queries without executing it immediately :)